# why Android App is crashing with UnsatisfiedLinkError?

Tags: java, android, react-native, mobile

I created a `react-native` app and published it yesterday. The app is crashing whenever I try to open it on a real device but is is `working in a simulator(using android studio)`. I collected a user sent crash report it is showing me this error. I am a beginner in android development and I don't know `java`.

I used `android app bundle`.

Can anyone help me to diagnose the error and what could I do to get more information regarding this and also how can I fix it.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
      at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName (SoLoader.java:314)
      at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary (SoLoader.java:247)
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit (ReactBridge.java:18)
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit> (NativeMap.java:19)
      at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.create (JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.java:21)
      at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run (ReactInstanceManager.java:912)
      at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:764)
```

I solved one issue after adding this into the `build.gradle` file. But now It is showing me an older version of the app and also dependency graph is not loaded. It is stuck. Help

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", 'armeabi', 'arm64-v8a'
  }
  packagingOptions {
           exclude "lib/arm64-v8a/libgnustl_shared.so"
           exclude '/lib/mips64/**'
           exclude '/lib/arm64-v8a/**'
           exclude '/lib/x86_64/**'
  }
```

Comment: You forgot to deploy some dependency? Error states that there's a library being loaded, which is present on your simulator but is missing on that real device, thus the error.

Comment: I don't think so... but how can I check which dependency I forgot?

Comment: Looks like you forgot a .so file.  If its working on the emulator but not on a device, its most likely that you included the x86 .so file but not the ARM one.

Comment: can you help me now? I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You have to upgrade the react-native version to 0.59 for supporting 64-bit native libs. http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/03/12/releasing-react-native-059